# Decoding JSON returns NULL

Tags: php, json

I am working with two php files, the first is creating a JSON and the second, should be able to read it (but doesnt work)

```
/*
Template Name: JANDERS

*/
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$myArr = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");

$myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

echo $myJSON;

?>
// Prints on screen:  ["John","Mary","Peter","Sally"]
```

And I want to see and use the JSON here:

```
<?php
$urlss = "https://example.com/22.php";

//call api
$jsonss = file_get_contents($urlss);

$jsontwoss = json_decode($jsonss);

var_dump(json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg());

//echo $json;
echo $jsontwoss;
?>
//returns    int(4) string(12) "Syntax error"
```

Whats wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: The way you've shared your code makes it look like the comment `/*JSON CREATOR*/` is outside the PHP block

Comment: It wasnt part of the file... edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo an array as string.

`$jsontwoss = json_decode($jsonss);`results in an array.

If you want to view your result just use

```
print_r($jsontwoss);
```

at line 12

Comment: Thank you for your help but even removing line 12, I receive the error as result of the "debug":
var_dump(json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg());